# htaccess redirect rule with URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect rule for the following condition,

`http://domain.com/go/usid/1/testeracc/newacc`

to

`http://domain.com/trk/link.php?uid=usid&page=1&test=testeracc&new=newacc`

I have directory created - 
`domain.com/go/`

I don't have any further directories

`/usid/1/testeracc/newacc` (those will generated dynamically)

Also let me know where I have to put `.htaccess` file in this process. 
is it in `domain.com/go/` ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your document/go directory's .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /go/ /trk/link.php?url=
</IfModule>
```

If u visit any site for example `http://domain.com/go/usid/1/testeracc/newacc`

You will get an array in the following manner

```
Array
(
     [url] => usid/1/testeracc/newacc
)
```

grab that and use where ever you want..

Comment: Thank User - user1777091

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^go/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /trk/link.php?uid=$1&page=$2&test=$3&new=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: How do I enable "httpd.conf" or How do I know it already enabled or not. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^go/userid/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /trk/link.php?uid=$1&page=1&test=$2&new=$3
</IfModule>
```

Put you .htaccess at your project root.